# MATLAB movie figure: dynamic data set

Tags: matlab, plot, movie

I'd like to preface this by saying that I'm quite new to MATLAB (and programming in general), so I would appreciate clear responses!

I have like 50 or so data sets that were taken at differing times (I'm basically looking at how a spectrum changes with time). Not all of the timings are equally spaced, nor are they all integers.

I want to plot the data like a movie to show how the data set changes with time.  I've managed to do make a dynamic plot using the following where I've removed all of the non-integer values because I didn't know how to deal with them (please excuse any inefficiencies or poor form):

```
    for k = [6:1:10 12:2:20 25:25:100 500 1000 2000:2000:20000 25000:5000:40000 50000 100000:100000:400000]
        plot(wl,sig(find(time==k),:))
        xlim([460 800])
        set(gca,'fontsize',24)
        ylabel('\Delta T')
        xlabel('Wavelength (nm)')
        M(k)=getframe; 
    end

    movie(M,3,10)
```

However, this simply lets you watch it plot all of the data sets one-by-one on the same figure.  At the end you're just left with a figure with 50 or so data sets all plotted together on the same figure.  This isn't what I want.  I want it to plot one data set for one time, then after some time that data set disappears and the next appears so that it looks like one whole living data set that is changing with time. (It would also be wonderful to be able to control the timing between each plot in a way that is representative of the real change in time.  Note that the k values are nanoseconds and I'd want to scale it by some realistic amount. I am not sure if this is possible or not.)

I'd also like to save the file as a movie format.  I'm not too worried about making MATLAB repeat the playback. It would also be really helpful to have a dynamic legend that shows the waiting time for each data set (the k value).

I know that this is a lot, but I would really appreciate any help! I'm hoping that this will generally help other people as well, since I'm sure that dynamic data sets are quite common in the physical sciences and being able to represent this in a presentation-friendly way is critical for talks.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a very broad question. If you have tried to implement the additional features you want, you may post your code, explain what is happening, and we can help you figure out why they aren't working. We don't implement new features for free.

Comment: you will get more help here if you at least try to implement the feature you want before asking how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to create a handle for each plot you create then call `delete()` on it right before you draw the next plot.  Otherwise, all plats will remain drawn as you have found out.

try something like this:

```
for k = [6:1:10 12:2:20 25:25:100 500 1000 2000:2000:20000 25000:5000:40000 50000 100000:100000:400000]
    if exist currentPlot
        delete(currentPlot);
    currentPlot = plot(wl,sig(find(time==k),:))
    xlim([460 800])
    set(gca,'fontsize',24)
    ylabel('\Delta T')
    xlabel('Wavelength (nm)')
    M(k)=getframe; 
end

movie(M,3,10)
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is for each plot to wait a bit before plotting the next one, you can do that with a `pause()` before the end of each loop. I.e. `pause(0.1)` pauses for 0.1s, and `pause` just pauses indefinitely until you press a key.

You can also create a *movie* structure, which plays as a movie *within* matlab as follows (toy example)

```
%% 
% *Create playable Movie structure within matlab*
X = [1:100];
k = 0; clear M;
for i = 1:0.01:10
  k = k + 1;
  Y = sin(i * X) ./ (X / i);
  plot(X,Y); 
  M(k) = getframe;
end
movie(M,1,25) % play the movie. (look at the help file for various
                       % options you can use to control the movie playback)
```

**or** you can use the technique below to write a proper video to a file.

```
%%
% *Export to video file*
Vid = VideoWriter('./output.avi');
open(Vid);
X = [1:100];
k = 0; clear M;
for i = 1:0.01:10
  k = k + 1;
  Y = sin(i * X) ./ (X / i);
  plot(X,Y); 
  axis([0 100 -2 2]) % size of video frames must not change!
  writeVideo(Vid,getframe);
end
close(Vid);
```